# Need help getting pm2 to run a react app that has webpack configured in a dev server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, pm2

Forgive me I am new to programming in general. I'm having trouble a lot of trouble trying to use pm2 to run a react app that has webpack set up. We are using an apache server for the production. For work we are trying to have the development server constantly running, the way that webpack dev server would have had it running so that more than one person can work on it at the same time. I thought I had enabled and got the app running but I am not sure if I am pointing to the wrong source file or if it should be pointing to a script or if I'm using the wrong interpreter.

I've looked into this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/774 but having installed webpack the react scripts stopped working because of babel-cli. I can't afford to go back to react scripts at this point since I spent so much time trying to configure webpack.

Was wondering if anyone can guide me as to where the script in the pm2 should point to for react? is it the index.js? or is it the webpack.config file that i set up? And if I'm using webpack where should I point the interpreter to if i have webpack set up with babel?

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my pm2 config file.

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [{
        name: "ucdirectorapp",
        script: "./src/index.js",
        watch: [
            "./build",
            "./public",
            "./src",
            ".babelrc",
            "package.json"
        ],
        watch_delay: 1000,
        ignore_watch: ["node_modules"],
        watch_options: {
            "followSymlinks": false
        },
        env: {
            name: 'ucdirector-dev',
            NODE_ENV: 'development',
            "PORT": 3000,
        },
        error_file: "./resource/log/pm2/err.log",
        out_file: "./resource/log/pm2/out.log",
        log_file: "./resource/log/pm2/log.log",
        max_memory_restart: "500M",
        interpreter: "./node_modules/@babel/cli/bin/babel.js"

    }],
};
```

I've been using this script pm2 start config/server/pm2.config.js --watch --interpreter ./node_modules/@babel/cli/bin/babel.js in the package.json

I get this error 
[PM2][ERROR] NVM is not available in PATH
[PM2][ERROR] Fallback to node in PATH

and I get a babel parse error. The app's status seem to be online but nothing is showing up on the host at port 3000 saying the site can't be reached and that it refused to connect.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not feasible... at least to my knowledge.  If you're working on the site from your laptop, with local code on your laptop, and I'm doing the same - how does the server know which to run? Even if the server is running files from a shared location - it sounds like trouble. I believe what you are wanting is a development CI/CD pipeline - so anyone can push code to a repo, it gets built, and displays the site.  Multiple people working off of 'shared' `.js` files that are hot reloading sounds like the formula for a bad time.

Comment: @MattOestreich we are working on it with the code in a remote host server, so this is not local code. Is there really no feasible way? The production build is using apache, but I am looking instead of node running it for pm2 to run it.

Comment: Well, you have to use some sort of a web server to serve your React code.. Furthermore, PM2 only works with node - so if you want to use PM2 you have to use node..The main issue is multiple people working on files that reside in a shared location. At the most basic level - think of it like working on a word document that lives on a file share somewhere - if person A already has the file open, and person B tries to open said shared word document, they get a message stating "someone already has this file open in read/write mode, would you like to open in read only?" There is a reason for that.

Comment: If the actual core codebase lives on a file share somewhere and you open it remotely, as well as one of your coworkers - then you work for 3 hours changing the contents of `somefile.js`, and at the same time he is also working on `somefile.js` - then you save your changes, and 5 minutes later he saves his changes - everything you did is overwritten. This is where things like Git repos come into play - you don't lose historical changes (aka version control)..

Comment: If I push local code to the repo, you get notified and can pull down that 'update' to the local code you are working on - you can run the dev server locally to see changes.. Furthermore, you can set up a CI/CD pipeline that automatically builds code pushed to a repo, then displays it for all to see.. That is the standard of how to handle many people working on a single codebase - something like Git. The logic behind how you want to handle this, by having multiple people work on some shared file(s) is fundamentally flawed. There is a reason Git is so big. Look more into Git and CI/CD pipelines.

Comment: This is also another reason why Docker is so popular. I can make changes to the code base, build the code locally into a container (before even pushing to a main repo), then you can download that image from the container repo (like Dockerhub or whatever) and run it in a container locally without having to worry about installing any garbage on your local machine. There are plenty of ways to handle what you are wanting to accomplish.. It just isn't as easy as 'put some project on a file share and let everyone work on it at the same time' - if you think about it, it is much more complex than that

Comment: Are you familiar with Git/Git repos at all? (like BitBucket, GitLab, GitHub, to name a few)